# Is voltage path independent outside a conductor (assuming constant magnetic field)

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, voltage

I've been reading about conservative vs non conservative fields.  I understand that in the presence of changing magnetism, voltage can be path dependent.  I want to know if voltage can be path dependent even in a constant magnetic field.  Here is an example of a circuit:

[image]

The circuit assumes no outside varying magnetic field.

In the red path from A to B, that goes through the wire and through the battery, the usual 1V is expected.

But what about the green path that starts at A, goes through the wire, leaves the circuit and goes around the battery, and back into the wire and ends up at B?  Shouldn't the voltage from that path be zero in an ideal wire, or slightly negative in a wire with small innate resistance?

I speculate that the answer may be even "outside a conductor" there is some small current due to finite resistance.  And this just isn't drawn in the diagram but still somehow makes the voltage along that path equal to the expected 1 volt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> I speculate that the answer may be even "outside a conductor" there is some small current due to finite resistance.

This isn't needed for the voltage to have a defined value in the space around the circuit.

Since there is a voltage difference between the wires on the two sides of the circuit, there is an electric field between them. So you can calculate the voltage at any point in that space from the formula
$$V_A-V_B=V_{AB}=\int_{\mathbf{r}_B}^{\mathbf{r}_A} \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\ell}.$$
If you start the integration at a point A whose voltage you know (like one terminal of the battery), then in principle you can get the voltage at any point in space.

It also works out that the integral won't depend on the path you use to get from A to B. This is a result of the fact that $\vec\nabla\times\vec{E}=0$ (because we assumed no changing magnetic fields in the system).

Comment: "Since there is a voltage difference between the wires on the two sides of the circuit, there is an electric field between them."  This to me seems to beg the question, and is just restating the definition of voltage.  How do we know there is an electric field?  What does it look like?

Comment: @DanielV, you can find what it looks like by solving Laplace's equation with appropriate boundary conditions.